# Connection refused by PLC when connecting with Milo OPC Client

Tags: opc, opc-ua, milo

I tried to clean up the ReadExample mini project for client repository from **Milo** **OPC**, and for endpoint i put the **PLC** **ip** address.

But there was no port in the plc configuration that i could configure. 
When i do not specify a port, it says i cannot open a port to it. 
If i specify a port, it says connection refused by the machine. 
Is it possible to connect the client to the **plc**? or was i just hoping?

Also, i did remove the server part from the example, as stated in some other questions here about this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the PLC have an embedded OPC UA server? Have you tried the default port 4840 yet?

Comment: i did not know there was a default port. i will try today and let you know. no it does not have an embbedded server. it is a xv series from EATON

Comment: If it does not have an embedded OPC UA server you're not going to be able to connect an OPC UA client to it.

Comment: i could not understand from documentation, do you happen to know how to connect the plc to the server in this case?

Comment: after realizing that i did not have the server, i tried with a server example, and got into further trouble. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821824/milo-opc-server-tries-to-connect-to-wrong-uri