# Milo OPC Server tries to connect to wrong URI

Tags: opc, milo

I tried to run an example server from Milo OPC repository, and I put as endpoint the ip of the PLC. In the device, the name of the device is "MI_027859".

```
19:18:36.748 [main] WARN  o.e.m.o.stack.core.util.EndpointUtil - Endpoint URL 'Illegal character in hostname at index 12: opc.tcp://MI_027859:12686/MI_027859' is not a valid URI: {}
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname at index 12: opc.tcp://MI_027859:12686/MI_027859
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHostname(URI.java:3387)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(URI.java:3236)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3155)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3097)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.parseServerAuthority(URI.java:915)
```

Comment: Which example are you trying to run? You're going to have to make some small modifications either way - the server you're trying to connect to is using an illegal character in its URL. It seems also though that you are still starting the Milo server and connecting the example to it.

Comment: i went with the breakpoint, adn when i put the endpoint as ip, it identifies the name of the plc as well, and tries toconnect to both the ip and the plc. The connection seems to work so far to the ip. i just had to filter out the ip.

Comment: On server side just set IP for endpoint 127.0.0.1